# In a WITH/RETURN with DISTINCT or an aggregation, it is not possible to access variables declared before the WITH/RETURN

Tags: neo4j

```
WITH $arrayHere as ids
    UNWIND ids as id
    MATCH(o:`App`)-[:ContainsFood]->(d:Food:`App`) WHERE id(o) = id
    RETURN DISTINCT {Document: d} ORDER BY d.Title"
```

On running this query I am getting the error -

```
In a WITH/RETURN with DISTINCT or an aggregation, it is not possible to access variables declared before the WITH/RETURN: d (line 5, column 42 (offset: 308))
"       RETURN DISTINCT {Food: d} ORDER BY d.Title"
```

I am trying to sort the resulting list based on the title but cant do so because of this error
Without using ORDER BY in the end I am getting the result correctly but I need it sorted which is not happening

Answer (score 0):

You have to first carry the node in with and do Order BY and then return the result. Your query would be

```
WITH $arrayHere as ids
UNWIND ids as id
MATCH(o:`App`)-[:ContainsFood]->(d:Food:`App`) WHERE id(o) = id
WITH DISTINCT d ORDER BY d.Title RETURN {Document: d}
```

Hope this helps!